# In a polygonal mesh 3d model which consist of triangles is it possible to separate different objects?

Tags: 3d, mesh, polygon

I have a 3d city model that is a collada file which consist of many triangles. When I select the model in a 3d software all buildings are selected. But I want every building to be selectable separately, is it possible? Are there any methods or algorithms that define which triangles belong to a building in a 3d model that consist many buildings and triangles?

Comment: Do the buildings have any properties that would help distinguish them? Are they disconnected items, or is the city a single connected mesh with the buildings rising from a plane?

Comment: yes absolutely second one a single connected mesh

Comment: It's worth editing to include that in your description.

Comment: Then it really depends on the buildings. Are all your buildings just cubes? Or at least convex? And is the ground plane really just a plane or has it terrain?